# Aligning the dimensions for conformity in matlab

Tags: matlab

A number of times, I run this simple code. It keeps displaying a usual error related to the dimensions but I have tried to extend the dimensions of rho_1. I am not sure if the error is mainly due to the CDF function. Any suggestions for solving this problem? Thanks

```
rho_1 = [2*10^-4];
beta=4;
Cua = pi*gamma(1+2/beta)*gamma(1-2/beta);
A = (4*pi-36*sqrt(3)+64)/(12*pi-9*sqrt(3));
p2=10^(15/10);
p1=10^(15/10);
T_1 = 10^(2/10);
T_2 = 10^(2/10);
B_one = 1/2*rho_1*Cua*((T_2)^(2/beta))*(A^2)*(((p2/p1)^(2/beta))+ 1); 
Ry_low = 0:10:50; A=(4*pi-36*sqrt(3)+64)/(12*pi-9*sqrt(3));
Ry_high = 50;
D_one= 1/2*rho_1*Cua*((T_2)^(2/beta)) * (A^2) *(((p1/p2)^(2/beta))+ 1) ;
C_rov = ((pi* rho_1)/(2* sqrt(B_one*D_one)*(Ry_high - Ry_low).^2))*((normcdf(sqrt(2*B_one)*Ry_high) - (normcdf(sqrt(2*B_one)*Ry_low))) *((normcdf(sqrt(2*D_one)*Ry_high) - (normcdf(sqrt(2*D_one)*Ry_low)))));
plot(Ry_low,C_rov)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dot multiplication/division. Also corrected D_1 to D_one.  Please replace your line 13 with this:

```
C_rov = ((pi* rho_1)./(2* sqrt(B_one*D_one).*(Ry_high - Ry_low).^2)).*((normcdf(sqrt(2*B_one)*Ry_high) - (normcdf(sqrt(2*B_one)*Ry_low))).*((normcdf(sqrt(2*D_one)*Ry_high) - (normcdf(sqrt(2*D_one)*Ry_low)))));
```